# Problema com mais de dois router-outlet no aplicativo

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routes, router

```
[...]
<header>
     <a routerLink="/lista-empresa" href="javascript:;">Empresa</a>
</header>
[...]
<main>
<router-outlet name="conteudo"></router-outlet>
</main>
[...]
```

**empresa.routing.module.ts**

```
const empresaRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: EmpresaListasComponent,
        outlet: 'conteudo'
    }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(empresaRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class EmpresaRoutingModule { }
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
const ROUTES:Routes=[
    {path:'', component:PrincipalComponent},
    {path:'lista-empresa', loadChildren:'app/empresa/empresa.module#EmpresaModule'}
];
@NgModule({
    imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)],
    exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class RoutingModule{}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Agora vamos ao problema.
Ao clicar no `routerLink`, o componente que deveria ser renderizado em `outlet=Conteudo` não funciona como esperado.
A página fica em branco.

Pelo que eu entendi na minha pesquisa, ao dar um nome para meu `router-outlet`.
O componente deveria ser renderizado dentro dele.
Onde estou errando ?

Obs: Esse é o Dom após selecionar a rota `lista-empresa`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloquei meu EmpresaComponent como filho de PrincipalComponent
e removi o parametro outlet do Router, removi o atributo nome do `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, e resolveu.

Carrega o componente empresa como filho de PrincipalComponent

```
 const PRINCIPAL_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: PrincipalComponent, 
    children:[
        {path: '', loadChildren: 'app/empresa/empresa.module#EmpresaModule'},        
    ]},

];
```

e no main do principal component

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Discussão completa no stackoverflow ingles [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151276/two-router-angular5-not-works)